# How to get mysqli working with DELIMITERs in SQL statements?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, delimiter

I'm using mysqli and trying now to get a view from an SQL code snippet (generated by MySQL Workbench) into a database.

```
$query = <<<QUERY
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `myview` ;
SHOW WARNINGS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `myview`;
SHOW WARNINGS;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `myview` AS

...view definition...

$$
DELIMITER ;

;
SHOW WARNINGS;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
QUERY;

$result = mysqli_multi_query($dbConnection, $query);
```

This doen't work. No errors, the statement seems just to be ignored. It only works, if I remove the delimiter definitions (lines `DELIMITER $$`, `$$`, and `DELIMITER ;`).

Why is it not working? What can/should I do to use delimiters in SQL statements passed to `mysqli` functions and methods?

Thx

Comment: You can't.  Use [`mysqli_query()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) to execute the entire `CREATE VIEW` operation (including its embedded `;` delimiters) as one single statement.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I cannot find anything about it in the [MySQLi docu](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). Could you please explain, why it is not posible. Or just provide a link you information source.

Comment: `DELIMITER` is a not a server-side statement.  It's a client-side command recognised by the `mysql` command-line client (and, probably, others too).  It is not recognised by the `mysqli` driver, hence there is nothing in the documentation.  The documentation does not mention any way for one to change the `mysqli` driver's statement delimiter.  I don't have any reference to cite.

Answer (score -2):

This is the source that helped me understand this...
http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/Problems-changing-the-sql-end-of-statement-delimiter-tp2124060p2124276.html

> DELIMITER is not an actual MySQL Statement.

I believe it is just something that some MySQL clients have implemented to help shipping a bunch of sql statements at the same time.

**mysqli driver** does not implement this functionality.

So, this should work.

```
$query = <<<QUERY
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `myview` ;
SHOW WARNINGS;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `myview`;
SHOW WARNINGS;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `myview` AS

...view definition...

;
SHOW WARNINGS;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
QUERY;

$result = mysqli_multi_query($dbConnection, $query);
```

I ran into the same problem, with the same mysqli driver, with multi_query function (using delimiters while creating procedures) and removing the *DELIMITER* from my SQL worked.

Comment: will not double quotation mark " have technically same effect as using <<<QUERY syntax ?