# Can't create procedure with mysqli, but can with phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

trying to create a stored procedure through mysqli in php. Keep throwing back at 1064 error when I do it through php, but is fine, when I copy the same sql command in php. Anyone able to shed some light on what could be the problem, or anyone found a solution to something similar?

Create Procedure code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE 6de443aacf727f6009e857480f33153cmakeLive (IN taskID INT, IN avaliableTime INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
        DECLARE a INT;
        DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT t.`task_id`
            FROM `task_dependency` d
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT `task_id`, `dependent_on_task_id`, ti.`id`, min(ti.`completed`) as make_live
                FROM `task_dependency`
                LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                    SELECT `task_id`, `completed` FROM `6de443aacf727f6009e857480f33153c_tasks`
                ) ti ON ti.`task_id` = `dependent_on_task_id`
                GROUP BY `task_id`
            ) t ON d.`task_id` = t.`task_id`
            WHERE d.`dependent_on_task_id` = taskID
                AND t.make_live > 0;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

        OPEN cur1;

        read_loop: LOOP
            FETCH cur1 INTO a;
            IF done THEN
                LEAVE read_loop;
            END IF;
            UPDATE `6de443aacf727f6009e857480f33153c_tasks` SET `live` = 1 WHERE `task_id` = a;
        END LOOP;

        CLOSE cur1;

        UPDATE `6de443aacf727f6009e857480f33153c_tasks` SET `earliest_start` = avaliableTime WHERE `task_id` IN (
            SELECT `task_id`
            FROM `task_dependency`
            WHERE `dependent_on_task_id` = taskID
        ) AND `earliest_start` < avaliableTime;
    END //
DELIMITER ;
```

PHP Code:

```
if (!$this->dbc->query("DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS " . $this->table_prefix . "makeLive") ||
    !$this->dbc->query($query)) {
    echo "Stored procedure creation failed: (" . $this->dbc->errno . ") " . $this->dbc->error . "<br /><br />" . $query;
    exit;
}
echo "success";
exit;
```

Script execution is throwing out the following error...

```
Stored procedure creation failed: (1064) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER //
        CREATE PROCEDURE 6de443aacf727f6009e857480f33153cmakeLive (IN tas' at line 1
```

Although it says it's a syntax error, the fact a straight copy and paste of the command to phpmyadmin seems to work, looks like it's gotta be some sort of mysqli bug perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

The query function only allows you to execute a single query.  Try the multi_query function (documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php ) instead.  It allows for multiple commands, and may fix your issue.

Comment: Cheers for that one, complete oversight there.

Comment: Separated the queries, but looks like it's having a problem with the DELIMITER //, pulls the error of 1064 for that, know if DELIMITER can't be run through mysqli->query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418218/how-to-get-mysqli-working-with-delimiters-in-sql-statements - Looks like DELIMITER's not possible with mysqli, fighting a losing cause here. Will have to find some other way. Although seems somewhat counterproductive if it's possible with the deprecated mysql functions

Comment: Sorry for the commentary, looks like mysqli->query runs the whole command, not just the first command upto the semi-colon, so the delimiter wasn't necessary, just issuing the command for the procedure

Answer (score 0):

Turns out mysqli->query already parses semi-colons and runs the whole command. The delimiter commands at the start and end of the query where unnecessary in successfully creating the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove DELIMITER and it will work. So in your case it will be like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 6de443aacf727f6009e857480f33153cmakeLive (IN taskID INT, IN avaliableTime INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE a INT;
    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT t.`task_id`
        FROM `task_dependency` d
        LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT `task_id`, `dependent_on_task_id`, ti.`id`, min(ti.`completed`) as make_live
            FROM `task_dependency`
            LEFT OUTER JOIN (
                SELECT `task_id`, `completed` FROM `6de443aacf727f6009e857480f33153c_tasks`
            ) ti ON ti.`task_id` = `dependent_on_task_id`
            GROUP BY `task_id`
        ) t ON d.`task_id` = t.`task_id`
        WHERE d.`dependent_on_task_id` = taskID
            AND t.make_live > 0;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    OPEN cur1;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cur1 INTO a;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        UPDATE `6de443aacf727f6009e857480f33153c_tasks` SET `live` = 1 WHERE `task_id` = a;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;

    UPDATE `6de443aacf727f6009e857480f33153c_tasks` SET `earliest_start` = avaliableTime WHERE `task_id` IN (
        SELECT `task_id`
        FROM `task_dependency`
        WHERE `dependent_on_task_id` = taskID
    ) AND `earliest_start` < avaliableTime;
END;
```