# save sql query to database to create report page

Tags: php, mysql, database, web

I have a question about how to set up a page in php to allow the user to create reports from a mysql database and display in a grid on the page.  I want them to build the query and save it to the another table and list on their report page to execute at anytime.  I would like to give them the ability to create as many report they want and they can manage them.  The site is access only and everyone has different permission levels.  I have been searching but had no luck.  Could someone either point me in the right direction or help me with setting up the script in php.  The problem for me is setting up the build query page to pull in all the different tables and then naming the report saving it.

Thanks 
Jon

Comment: If your server supports VIEWS, that's your solution.  You should be able to have your user create their query, save it as a view.  Then from that point forward, it will be available as if it were a table.

Comment: It does but how would I set up the build page to save them and then display back for them to call at a later time.

Answer (score 0):

Due to JS errors, I cannot add another comment.  But I found you a solution right here on SO.  How to create a view from PHP:  [How to create a view with mysqli_multi_query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15411710/how-to-create-a-view-with-mysqli-multi-query)